# Clojure RT/Compiler: How to Iterate through forms?

Tags: java, forms, clojure, compiler-construction, compilation

I am working on a Java project that has some Clojure involved.  I know how to run compile and run clojure code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RT.init();
    runCode();
}

public static Object runCode() {
    String str = "(ns my-ns)" +
        "(defn add [a b] (+ a b))" +
        "(println (add 1 2))";

    Compiler.load(new StringReader(str));

    /* I know how to invoke it: */
    Var foo = RT.var("my-ns", "add");
    return foo.invoke(1,2);
}
```

What would be very useful at the point is to have a way to iterate over forms in Java, and in some sense "analyze" the compiler output.  Basic things I want to know is:

1. What is the text source of a form?
2. What function is being called in a form.
3. What arguments are being passed to the function (forms are ok)
4. Be able to do this on top level forms, or drill in as needed.

Is there a way to do this using the clojure compiler, or runtime (or other Java classes in Clojure?)  I see such compiler methods as analyze, for example:

```
Expr target = analyze(C.EXPRESSION, RT.second(form));
```

Though its not clear to me yet how form was constructed, and there are no Javadoc :-).  Do I need to go [The Compiler Source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) and figure out how it works?

Comment: You should use http://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/java/api/package-summary.html

Comment: And there is https://github.com/clojure/tools.analyzer - you could export the functionality you need with said API.